# FBWebDialogs is Missing Session Cookie to validate user

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am fetching a facebook token from my server (where it was stored from a previous login on another device). I am using that to open a session and then I am making a relatively simple call with

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession]
                                                  message:@"Message"
                                                    title:@"Title"
                                               parameters:params
                                                  handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result,
                                                  NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}}];
```

The web window that pops up has a message saying "An Error occured. Please try again later.". I click OK and I trigger the callback (which I omitted above). When I trace the resultURL I get

```
fbconnect://success?error_code=110&error_msg=Missing+user+cookie+%28to+validate+session+user%29
```

I can use the session to post on my wall just fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Have u resolved that issue?

Comment: Wow, its a long time ago now. I can't say I did. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the token retuned by Facebook contains additional metadata such as the c_user cookie which is used by all web views subsequently. When setting up a remote caching system you must store expiry date and refresh date on the remote server and return them for use in the TokenData object. If this is not done correctly them the correct metadata is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have "publish_actions" permission on your active Facebook session.

```
    bool hasPublishPermission = NO;
    for( NSString* permission in [FBSession.activeSession permissions] )
    {
        if( [permission isEqualToString:@"publish_actions"] )
        {
            hasPublishPermission = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( !hasPublishPermission )
    {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                              allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                             FBSessionState status,
                                                             NSError *error) {
                                             if( status==FBSessionStateOpen )
                                             {
                                                 //Present dialog
                                             }
                                         }];
    }
    else
    {
        //Present dialog
    }
```

Also, make sure you have added your "FacebookAppID" to your project's plist. (See the tab, "Configure a new Xcode Project", at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/ ) This may cause the error you are describing.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have integrated  **Embedded webview** in my app with  Facebook sdk 3.5.3

I hope my code will give some idea to you...

```
-(IBAction)fblogin:(id)sender{
         NSArray * arr=[NSArray                arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"email",@"basic_info",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_likes", nil];

        Interest_Status=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txt_interest.text];
            [FBSession  setActiveSession:session];

        if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
            if ([btn_Login.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Logout"]) {

                [btn_Login setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [btn_Login setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FBLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


                FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy *tokenCachingStrategy = [[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy alloc]
                                                                       initWithUserDefaultTokenInformationKeyName:nil];

                tokenCachingStrategy=nil;
                FBSession *seession=[FBSession activeSession];
                [seession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
                [session close];
                [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
                session=nil;

                session=[[FBSession alloc]initWithPermissions:arr];
                self.ProfileLale.hidden=YES;


            }
            /*else if ([btn_Login.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Login"]) {
                    [self updateForSessionChangeForSlot:1];
            }*/


        }else{
            [session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorForcingWebView
                    completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                        FBSessionState status,
                                        NSError *error) {
                            // this handler is called back whether the login succeeds or fails; in the
                            // success case it will also be called back upon each state transition between
                            // session-open and session-close
                        if (error)
                                {
                                    NSLog(@"error=%@ \n\n description=%@ \n\n,",error,error.description);
                                    [self switchToNoActiveUser];
                                }else{
                                    [self updateForSessionChangeForSlot:1];
                                }
                    }];

        }
 }




- (void)updateForSessionChangeForSlot:(int)slot {
   if (session.isOpen) {
                // fetch profile info such as name, id, etc. for the open session
                // Fetch user data
            FBRequest *me = [[FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:session
                                                     graphPath:@"me"];

            [me startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                             NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
                                             NSError *error) {
                    // because we have a cached copy of the connection, we can check
                    // to see if this is the connection we care about; a prematurely
                    // cancelled connection will short-circuit here
                    //   if (me != self.pendingRequest) {
                    //      return;
                    //  }
                  NSLog(@"user=%@",user);

                    //  self.pendingRequest = nil;
                    //  self.pendingLoginForSlot = -1;

                    // we interpret an error in the initial fetch as a reason to
                    // fail the user switch, and leave the application without an
                    // active user (similar to initial state)
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"error=%@",error);
                    NSLog(@"Couldn't switch user: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    [self switchToNoActiveUser];
                    return;
                }else{
                     NSLog(@"user=%@",user);
                     [btn_Login setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                     [btn_Login setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FBLogout.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                }
            }];

        } else {
                // in the closed case, we check to see if we picked up a cached token that we
                // expect to be valid and ready for use; if so then we open the session on the spot
            if (session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
                    // even though we had a cached token, we need to login to make the session usable
                [session openWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                     FBSessionState status,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                    [self updateForSessionChangeForSlot:slot];
                }];
            }
        }

  }



- (void)switchToNoActiveUser {

      /*UIAlertView *alter=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"No Internet connecton" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alter show];
       */
         NSArray * arr=[NSArray             arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"email",@"basic_info",@"user_location",@"user_birthday",@"user_likes", nil];

        session = nil;
        session=[[FBSession alloc]initWithPermissions:arr];
        [btn_Login setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.ProfileLale.hidden=YES;
        [btn_Login setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FBLogin.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am creating a session from a token that has been retrieved from my server, where it was stored from a previous login from another device...